# A simple question on measure of difference.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $E\subseteq X$. Let $F,G\in\mathcal{A}$ such that $$F\subseteq E\subseteq G,\quad\text{and}\quad \mu(G\setminus F)=0$$

**Question.** Can I conclude that $\mu(G)=\mu(F)$?

For me, the answer is yes, since $G=F\sqcup(G\setminus F)$, then $\mu(G)=\mu(F)+\mu(G\setminus F)=\mu(F)$.

It's correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: (1) Yes, you can. (2) Your derivation of the result is correct too.

Comment: Why is $E$ given? It has nothing to do with what is shown. Is there perhaps also a question about $\mu(E)$?

Comment: @md2perpe In reality this is only a passage of a more general proof, in particular of the completion of a measure space. However, I only needed to know what I said in the post.

Comment: @Nat. That's what I thought.